# Keyboard/mouse undetected after installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, ssd, keyboard, input-device

Afterwards, I installed Windows 10 (over Windows 7) on my SSD. First start was ok, keyboard and mouse were working fine. I shut it down and came back hours later to discover that I cannot input anything anymore with any keyboard.

I tried every USB port I have on my desktop : none of them works.

I read reckon that it could be drivers : I unplugged the SSD since Windows 7 is still installed on the other HDD. Doesn't work either.

Also tried PS/2 ports : doesn't work.

So I am stuck at BIOS password I set up for the first time a day ago.

[BIOS password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PORVR.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is probably a driver problem not resolve in the upgrade (depending on how old the Windows 7 machines was).  Try starting with a bootable USB key. If that works (Keyboard and Mouse) and you still cannot start normally, you may need to back up your data and install Windows 10 fresh.

Comment: I also tried that but I am asked the BIOS password before anything else... which I can't type in.

Comment: If you cannot remember the BIOS password you set up, then I am not sure if you can fix it.

Comment: I do remember it, but can't type it since the keyboard isn't recognized

Comment: When you are starting with USB, can you try a different keyboard.?

Comment: I did indeed, two different keyboards. None of them seems to turn on (trying with numlock to check the light or even typing in doesn't input anything)

Comment: Tried every USB port ; front and rear

Comment: I wonder if you set the BIOS password also as a hard drive password

Comment: I'll try that quick :)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes

Comment: replace the batteries on your wireless keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Nice try ahah. It's cable